# Mongo documentation: what is query, expression, query predicate and clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB documentation uses words like *query*, *expression*, *query predicate*, *clause* but I'm unable to find their precise meaning.

For example syntax of `$elemMatch` is defined as

```
{ <field>: { $elemMatch: { <query1>, <query2>, ... } } }
```

but I don't know what does `query1`, `query2` mean. The same article about `$elemMatch` mentions word query predicate:

> If you specify a single query predicate in the `$elemMatch` expression, `$elemMatch` is not necessary.

But they don't specify what does it mean. Is there a place in the documentation (or in Mongo source code) where these words are precisely defined?

---

To be more concrete: I'm trying to understand how to form valid queries. For example why with this database

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ {value: 49} ] }
]);
```

following query works

```
db.inventory.find( {dim_cm: { $elemMatch :{ $or: [{value: 49}] } }} )
```

but query without `$elemMatch` doesn't:

```
db.inventory.find( {dim_cm: { $or: [{value: 49}] } })
```

Even though the documentation states *If you specify a single query predicate in the `$elemMatch` expression, `$elemMatch` is not necessary.*

Comment: I think you should post the collection and output you want instead of all these...

Comment: *"but query without $elemMatch doesn't:"* - Because on a "single predicate" you simply use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) `db.inventory.find( {"dim_cm.value": { "$in": [49]  } } }`. The only time you would use `$elemMatch` with an "inner" `$or` condition ( or `$in ) would be because there was an "array" inside the array element itself. Instead of asking questions about the manual, simply show your data and what you expect to return as a result. If you don't understand the documentation then you're probably looking at the wrong operators anyway.

Comment: In fact, as just pointed out you **are** looking at the wrong operators.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I'm actually trying to write a library for Mongo which will make it impossible to form invalid queries - invalid query won't compile (this is strictly better than existing libraries which let you form queries which fail when you execute them). But to do so I need to understand which queries are valid and which not. So I was trying to understand documentation - which seems imprecise and sometimes wrong (like in my example where it states that `$elemMatch` is not necessary but in reality it doesn't work without it).

Comment: @RadekMicek you can find the glossary part here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/

Answer (score -1):

The `$elemMatch` operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria. Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) link

To get better understanding of mongodb you can start from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/) .

Mongodb also provides free courses for new learners. Check [this](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about?jmp=homepage&_ga=2.201171820.358261760.1526304725-1876185584.1523882492).

Comment: Yeah but from that documentation it's still not clear what **precisely** is query or expression. I can see these words in many parts of the documentation but I cannot find any precise explanation (I found unofficial BNF https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-language-model/blob/master/docs/bnf.md but definitions there differ from official documentation).

Comment: You will understand mongodb when you practice along with examples. Just reading the docs won't help you.